# Disable logging in thymeleaf?

Tags: thymeleaf

I´m new at Thymeleaf.

How can I disable the Logging? Currently I will get always in my console a huge logging? How can I disable it?

```
public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        StringTemplateResolver templateResolver = new StringTemplateResolver();
        templateResolver.setTemplateMode(TemplateMode.HTML);
        
        TemplateEngine templateEngine = new TemplateEngine();
        templateEngine.setTemplateResolver(templateResolver);
  
        String templateString = "<p>Hello, [[${name}]]!</p>";

        Context context = new Context();
        context.setVariable("name", "John Doe");

        StringWriter stringWriter = new StringWriter();
        templateEngine.process(templateString, context, stringWriter);

        System.out.println(stringWriter.toString());
    }

}
```

I´m using:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.thymeleaf</groupId>
  <artifactId>thymeleaf</artifactId>
  <version>3.1.2.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

I want only to catch Exception...

Comment: Variations of this question [have been asked before](https://www.google.com/search?q=thymeleaf+logging+site%3Astackoverflow.com). Even those questions with no answer, but only comments, contain useful information.

Comment: Also, have you [reviewed the official documenation](https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/3.1/usingthymeleaf#logging)? Did you try any specific logging settings? If so, show us what you tried.